# Recovering the Weinstein Splitting Theorem for Poisson manifolds using the Local Splitting theorem for Lie algebroids

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, poisson-geometry, lie-algebroids

How can I recover the Weinstein Splitting Theorem for Poisson manifolds using the Local Splitting theorem for Lie algebroids? I am using the formulation of the theorem given in

> Rui Loja Fernandes, *Lie Algebroids, Holonomy and Characteristic Classes*, Advances in Mathematics **170** (2002) pp 119–179, doi:[10.1006/aima.2001.2070](https://doi.org/10.1006/aima.2001.2070), arXiv:[math/0007132](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0007132).

On Page 13, Fernades gives the following hint:

> In general, the structure functions that appear in relations (11) will depend both on the $x$'s and $y$'s variables, subject to (12). For special classes of Lie algebroids one might have extra information that leads to further simplification of the structure functions. For example, in the case of a Poisson manifold, one always has the relationship:
>   $$
> c^{ij}_k = \frac{\partial b^{ij}}{\partial x^k}.
> $$
>   Then, all structure functions in (11) depend only on the $y$'s variables, and one obtains the Weinstein Splitting Theorem.

I made some fruitless attempts =(